# Setting a default checkbox value in FAPI

Tags: 7, forms, entities

Trying to set a default value on an entity reference field.

```
$unitid = node_load($unit);
$form['field_choose_a_service']['und']['#default_value'] = $unitid;
```

> Warning: Illegal offset type in form_type_checkboxes_value() (line
>   2390 of
>   /homepages/43/d503288075/htdocs/example.co.uk/includes/form.inc).
>
> Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in
>   form_process_checkboxes() (line 3316 of
>   /homepages/43/d503288075/htdocs/example.co.uk/includes/form.inc).

And targeting the nid from that loaded node...

```
$unitid = node_load($unit);
$form['field_choose_a_service']['und']['#default_value'] = $unitid->nid;
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   form_type_checkboxes_value() (line 2389 of
>   /homepages/43/d503288075/htdocs/example.co.uk/includes/form.inc).

The first one actually works, but kicks up the errors. What am I doing wrong?

Essentially I want to check if the nid im passing in the URL as a _GET query matches an option in the entity reference checkbox options, and make that option selected if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```php
$unitid = node_load($unit);
$form['field_choose_a_service']['und']['#default_value'] = array($unitid->nid);
```

And please note that `node_load` returns an object but not a ID. I see you use `$unitid` as the variable name. It can make people confused.

Comment: I supposed that `$unitid` should be a node as it is the value from `node_load()`....

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'm guessing that worked because the default value is expecting an array, even if there is only one? Thanks!

Comment: @Collins I think field uses `checkboxes` rather than `checkbox` in all cases. And `checkboxes` only accept array as value. And the error happen on `form_type_checkboxes_value()` can prove it.